# What are the uses of dl_bw and dl_bandwidth? what are the differences between them?

Tags: linux-kernel, real-time, scheduling, scheduler, job-scheduling

I have read about the struct rt_bandwidth and that dl_bw is a sub-quota of rt_bw. What do rt_bw,  rt_bandwidth, dl_bw and dl_bandwidth do?